# How to get the image object by uid in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x, fluid-styled-content

In the [Viewhelper Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Image.html) you write:

```
    <f:image image="{imageObject}" />
```

What I need is the {imageObject}  as an output by an sys_file_reference uid input.

Is there any viewhelper (fluid or vhs)to get the {imageObject} by an sys_file_reference uid?

... I am afraid I have to write the viewhelper by my self. :-(

Comment: If you'r goal is to display the image you can do so by using `src` and `treatIdAsReference`: `<f:image src="{id}" treatIdAsReference="1" />`.